# Remove double slash from url using HaProxy settings

Tags: haproxy

I want to remove double slash from url once it hit my haproxy.
for example:

http://myhostname.com//restOfThePath to http://myhostname.com/restOfThePath

I am not able to get the right command and regex

Answer (score 2):

```
reqrep ^([^:\ ]+\ +)/(/.+)$ \1\2 if { path_beg // }
```

...but how does the double slash get into the request to begin with?  Browsers are very unlikely to send such a request.  This suggests you have a mistake elsewhere in your stack, and you should fix that error, rather than correcting it in HAProxy.